# gcc : Why does the generated code change with -funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=0/1

Tags: c, loops, gcc, compiler-optimization

I was playing around with the gcc's loop unrolling pass.I noticed that my program's executable size increases by few tens of Kilobytes when I specify "-funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=0/1".

I tested on some tiny testbench and saw the generated code has different set of basic blocks - the generated code is very similar (just slighltly reordered in some parts). The code size always increases with all my testbench with "-funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=0/1" - am not sure how a different layout of instructions amongst the basic blocks will result in the different size of the binary.

Why is the generated code different with " -funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=0/1" ? On debugging, the loop unroll pass correctly bails out doing nothing. So what exactly is causing this behavior ?

I can always remove the complete "-funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=0/1" clause from CFLAGS in order to disable the loop unrolling, but I am curious to know the reason the generated code is different.

Comment: Do you understand what loop unrolling does? If so, why would you expect to see the same code generated?

Comment: @keshlam, Please note that I am restricting the loop unrolling by setting a very low number for "max-unrolled-insns". If you look at the code in loop-unroll.c, this parameter is used to restrict the number of iterations to unroll. So my question is as this " -funroll-loops --param max-unrolled-insns=0/1" is really restricting the loop unrolling to do nothing, why is there a change in the generated code at all ?

Comment: You've requested that the compiler go through an additional path. It's likely to change *some* code -- perhaps loop-unrolling also performs invariant extraction. If that isn't what you had in mind, you shouldn't have given the compiler the opportunity.